Dokku: Error 521 when trying to view the Ruby demo app
I'm trying to learn Dokku and following the "Deploying an Application" tutorial, using their ruby-getting-started example project.
I've run git push dokku main without issues, and added an A record in Cloudflare to point from the ruby-getting-started subdomain to the IP address of the droplet.
When I visit the URL, I get Cloudflare's "Web Host is down" / 521 error screen.
Dokku's logs don't seem to show any access records or other errors. It's as if it's not receiving the request.

After lots of Googling, it turned out it was because my $5/mo 1-GB-of-RAM Digital Ocean droplet didn't have enough RAM to build the Ruby on Rails demo app.
